# Kubernetes NGINX Ingress changes HTTP request from a POST to a GET

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I'm using Kubernetes that is bundled with Docker-for-Mac. I'm trying to configure an Ingress that routes http requests starting with /v1/ to my backend service and /ui/ requests to my Angular app.

My issues seems to be that the HTTP method of the requests are changed by ingress (NGINX) from a POST to a GET.

I have tried various rewrite rules, but to no avail. I even switched from Docker-for-Mac to Minikube, but the result is the same.

If I use a simple ingress with no paths (just the default backend) then the service is getting the correct HTTP method.
The ingress below works:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: backend
    servicePort: 8080
```

But this ingress does not:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"

spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /v1
        backend:
          serviceName: backend
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /ui
        backend:
          serviceName: webui
          servicePort: 80
```

When I debug the "backend" service I see that the HTTP Request is a GET instead of a POST.

I read somewhere that NGINX rewrites issue a 308 (permanent) redirect and the HTTP method is changed from a GET to a POST, but if that is the case how can I configure my ingress to support different paths for different services that require POST calls?

Comment: can you try this adding annotation in ingress `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, but it just rewrites all endpoints to /

I event tried the following:
```
...
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
...
 - path: /v1(|$)(.*)
```

which rewrites the endpoints correctly, but still changes the HTTP method.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution to my problem. When I add `host:` to the configuration then the http method is not changed. Here is my current ingress yaml (the rewrite and regex are used to omit sending the /v1 as part of the backend URL)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /v1(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: gateway
          servicePort: 8080
```